# What is the PDF of $F(x,y)=1-e^{-x-y}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Where the support is $x+y>0$. Taking partial $x$ partial $y$ reveals $f(x,y)=-e^{-x-y}$, but we know density must be non-negative. What is wrong here?

The CDF seem to satisfy all conditions of a CDF so it doesn't seem like there is a problem with the CDF itself.
(1) $F(x,-\infty)=0, F(-\infty,y)=0,F(\infty,\infty)=1$
(2) F is increasing in both x and y
(3) F is right continuous.

Comment: Does $F$ also satisfy the condition $F(b,b')-F(a,b')-F(a',b)+F(a,a')\geq0$ for $a,a',b,b'$ with $a<b$ and $a'<b'$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik to find the pdf. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Densities_associated_with_multiple_variables).

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I believe the point is we want a "density" $d$, such that $F(x,y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y d(s,t)\,dsdy$.

Comment: it looks as though the assumptions here on the definition of a multivariate CDF are not enough. It seems quite likely that for a function to be a 2D cdf, we must have that its associated pdf would be positive everywhere. In other words, it isn't a distribution.

Comment: It seems as though the bivariate exponential distribution looks roughly like this:

$F(x,y) = 1-\exp(-\lambda_1 x-\lambda_2 y -\lambda_3 \max(x,y))$.

This is just out of some literature: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3819/54d8b366441de34af90698c6955e5eb01cf1.pdf

Comment: I feel one should also address the misunderstanding by the OP : if there is a characterization of the cdf of real valued random variables by the 3 properties the OP mentions as (1) (2) and (3), these are only necessary conditions in case of a couple of random variables, but no more sufficient conditions !

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is indeed a CDF and this of $(X,Y)$ then for $r>0$ we find: $$0\leq P(0<X\leq r,0<Y\leq r)=F(r,r)-F(r,0)-F(0,r)+F(0,0)=$$$$(1-e^{-2r})-2(1-e^{-r})+0=2e^{-r}-e^{-2r}-1$$

However if e.g. $e^{-r}=0.1$ then $2e^{-r}-e^{-2r}-1=-0.81<0$.

We conclude that $F$ is not a CDF.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Do you understand the reasoning that is behind it? In a decent script about probability and multivariable CDF's in special it must be mentioned that $F(a,b)-F(a',b)-F(a,b')+F(a',b')$ is the probability of $\{a'<X\leq a, b<Y\leq b'\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out! I was making practice questions for my students and I was completely baffled by this question myself.

Comment: You are very welcome.